# How to build Windows binaries such as adb.exe when building AOSP in Linux

Tags: android, adb, android-source, android-soong, android-make

I build AOSP on branch android-13.0.0_r41 with the following command:

```bash
. build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_arm-eng
m all -j$(nproc)
```

Some environment variables:

```
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=13
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_arm
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-5.4.0-150-generic-x86_64-Ubuntu-20.04.5-LTS
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=TQ2A.230405.003.E1
OUT_DIR=out
```

Althought the HOST_CROSS_OS environment variable is set to windows, but no Windows binary is built. I search with `find out -name '*.exe'`, and nothing is found. I also look for other targets of `m` command, but can not find a suitable target. How can I build Windows binaries as well when building AOSP in Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per the official documents you still need to build the target `win_sdk` and/or `winsdk-tools` then you should be able to see the required output in `out/host/**` directory.

Official ref: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/master/docs/howto_build_SDK.txt#110

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you have content under: `out/host/windows-x86` 
Windows binaries are generated by the cross compiler.